# Django: Operations on different fields of two different models

Tags: python, django, model

here two classes are defined, i would like to do some calculations on different field of both models.

```
class A(models.Model):
    newspaper = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Language)
    wh_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)
    sa_price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)

class B(models.Model):
    added_date = models.DateField(max_length=32,auto_now_add=True)
    newspaper = models.ForeignKey(Newspaper,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    qty_return =models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)
```

total (from B) = wh_price (from A) * qty (from B)

Comment: Can you please properly indent the code, also specify *what* you want. Maybe include some sample data and some sample output.

Comment: newspaper is foriegnkey Models A is newspaper. so when i give newspaper and qty. total have to automatically calculate save total colum.  so this actually need

Answer (score 0):

you can overide the save function of class b as following:

```
class Intake(models.Model):
    # your fields..
    # below is the save function which we are overriding
    save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total = self.newspaper.wh_price * self.qty
        super(Intake, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

this will serve the purpose as far as i understand the question.

Comment: when i select newspaper and put qty but total value not calculate. may i have to connect pk also ?

Comment: i did. but not value saved in the total data field.

Comment: then just show your views and update your code.. that was all i could tell according to the info u provided

Comment: **Here these are the code:** def save(self, Newspaper, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Intake, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            self.total = newspaper.wh_price * self.qty
            self.save()

Comment: u can do this way as u already have newspaper as a foreign key.. self.total = self.newspaper.wh_price * self.qty

And do tell me if instance of newly created model is saved or only the total data field is not getting populated. I would like to see the views.py where u are saving an instance of Intake

Comment: A.model has to save to newspaper name and price. B model is how much newspaper take for day. so  i have to add newspaper name only. that is foreign key  its automatically come. 2nd if enter qty of the newspaper. total data field calculate price and automatically have to  save with total data field. **This is actually want**

Comment: how can i share with view.py  is it any way to?

Comment: edit your question.. adding all the relevent code which is anyhow related to this issue

Comment: view.py    class IntakeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Intake.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IntakeSerializer

    def save(self, Newspaper, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Intake, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.total = newspaper.wh_price * self.qty
        self.save()

Comment: please see my edit in the comment.. you are not overiding the save function for intake class..

Comment: I try as your way but not calculate **here code** class Intake(models.Model):
  added_date  = models.DateField(max_length=32,auto_now_add=True)
  newspaper  = models.ForeignKey(Newspaper, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  qty     = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  qty_return  = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  total   = models.IntegerField(default=0)
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Intake, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            self.total = self.newspaper.wh_price * self.qty
            self.save()

Comment: share your code, only then i could help you figure out. Push it on github and send the link

Comment: here  i have to attache  https://github.com/Ravindrakumara/Newspaper_tracking

Comment: Thanks harry. i made it but when i enter newspaper and qty error occur  **RecursionError at /admin/NewspaperAPI/intake/add/

maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object**

Comment: i remove view.py save function but still come same **RecursionError at /admin/NewspaperAPI/intake/add/ maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object**

Comment: is it possible to insert data Models (A) to Models (B) for every day automatically